# Convert milliseconds to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsdate

I have this "1273636800000" and I want to convert it to this format "Wed Mar 03 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"

I need to convert this milliseconds to NSDate format.

I tried this

`NSDate *tr = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1273636800000];`

and

`NSDate *tr = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:1273636800000];`

and

`NSDate *tr = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1273636800000];`

But I can't get it to work, anyone had a similar problem and found the solution

Comment: What did `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` do? Did you account for timezones?

Comment: I just nee dthe date... I dotn care about Time..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These functions (dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970, dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow) accept parameter in seconds.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(ms / 1000.0)];
```

You should pass 1273636800.000

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(1273636800 / 1000.0)];
```

Comment: I spent a week looking around for this, if you think 3 hours is dumb, what should I call myself? XD

Answer (score 5):

Divide by 1000 to get millis in seconds, that's what you want.

Answer (score 4):

A simple one-line Swift 2 function:

```
func dateFromMilliseconds(ms: NSNumber) -> NSDate {
    return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:Double(ms) / 1000.0)
}
```