# How can I convert date in milliseconds to corresponding date in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, datetime

I need to convert date in milliseconds (Date(1322030548000+0530)) into corresponding date like Thu Sep 29 20:56:00 GMT+02:00 (its just an example). How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDate Convert milliseconds to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741199/nsdate-convert-milliseconds-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to look for is code such as:

```
dateWithTimeIntervalSince*:seconds
```

where * is 1970, Now, ReferenceDate

An example and answer is given in the link here:
[Convert milliseconds to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741199/nsdate-convert-milliseconds-to-nsdate)

Comment: i tired but i got value like this  43905-05-17 19:54:51 +0000, its not correct.

Comment: ya, got it. I have add a ponit like 1322030548.000. Thanks!