# How to Convert a milliseconds to nsdate in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, instagram

In `instagram` API,I got the below response

> "created_time" = 1379598284;

I want to convert the `created_time` to `NSDate`

please help me

Comment: Tones of answer on this topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741199/nsdate-convert-milliseconds-to-nsdate

this might help.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(ms / 1000.0)];
```

Answer (score 2):

simple try this...

```
  NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:yourtime];
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

try this... as per follow to decode to date

```
NSDate *tr = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1379598284];
```

or

```
NSDate *tr = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:1379598284];
```

OR

```
NSDate *tr = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1379598284];
```

Comment: Is this helpful to you??

Answer (score 0):

This is "**2013-09-19 13:44:44 +0000**" Try following line of code.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1379598284];
```